# Merge multiple arrays into one with unique values php

Tags: php, mysql

I know that there are a lot of similar threads on Stack Overflow, but none of them works in my case.

My goal is to get the unique show genres from the database. They are stored (1,2,3 or more) comma separated in the show_genres column.

```
$link = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'pw', 'db');
$query = "SELECT show_genres FROM tv_shows";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
foreach ($result as $value) {
$sh_genres = $value['show_genres'];
$sh_genres_array = array_map('trim', explode(',',$sh_genres));

// $doesnt_work = call_user_func_array("array_merge", 
$sh_genres_array); // doesn't work for me


echo '<pre>' . var_export($sh_genres_array, true) . '</pre>';
}
```

My result is as follows:

```
array (
  0 => 'Drama',
  1 => 'Action',
  2 => 'Crime',
)
array (
  0 => 'Drama',
  1 => 'Crime',
)
array (
  0 => 'Drama',
  1 => 'Thriller',
)
array (
  0 => 'DIY',
)
array (
  0 => 'Drama',
  1 => 'Mystery',
  2 => 'Supernatural',
)
```

However, I need just one array which contains the **unique values**, such as:

```
array (
  0 => 'Drama',
  1 => 'Mystery',
  2 => 'Supernatural',
  4 => 'Thriller',
  5 => 'DIY',
  6 => 'Crime',
  7 => 'etc...'

)
```

If I try to create some array before the foreach loop and then store the data into it, such approach doesn't give a result as well.

Perhaps, there is a more simple solution by the means of SQL!?!?

Comment: You should normalize your database. Then the current problem would be a simple database query.

Comment: Can you please suggest me how to normalize it? Just a simple example. Thanks. Of course, in such a case, it should be a simplest query :-)

Comment: Add a table with `genres` and another table linking `tv_shows` to genres.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try this code

**In SQL**

$query = "SELECT show_genres FROM tv_shows GROUP BY show_genres";

**In PHP**

```
$newArray  = array();

foreach ($result as $value) {

  $sh_genres = $value['show_genres'];
  $sh_genres_array = array_map('trim', explode(',',$sh_genres));

  $newArray = array_merge($newArray , $sh_genres_array );    

}

$newUniqueArray = array_unique($newArray);
```

Comment: I might try to do like this, but my arrays are unnamed

Comment: I understand the idea, but in such a case I would have to create some additional foreach loop to mark my arrays some way. But I have no idea how to accomplish it.

Comment: This is exactly how I tried to cope with my goal, but I stumbled upon two issues: 1) When I'm trying to var_dump $newArray, I can't get a result

Comment: 2) $newUniqueArray gives me just about 26 genres, which is impossible )))

Comment: You want to get all the unique values of show_genres  from database?

Comment: Exactly... all of them! I suppose, there are about 150-200 genres... or more

Comment: **SELECT show_genres FROM tv_shows GROUP BY show_genres** => use GROUP BY then, also added to answer

Comment: Looks like this approach works! The key idea I couldn't realize that I can merge $newArray , $sh_genres_array. Thanks everyone for participating!

Answer (score 2):

try using this code

```
    $link = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'pw', 'db');
    $query = "SELECT show_genres FROM tv_shows";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    $sh_genres_array = [];
    foreach ($result as $value) {
    $sh_genres = $value['show_genres'];
    $sh_genres_array = array_merge(
        $sh_genres_array ,
        array_map('trim', explode(',',$sh_genres))
    );
}
echo '<pre>' . var_export(array_unique($sh_genres_array), true) . '</pre>';
```

**Update**

Please consider normalizing your database

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but try this.

```
 $genre_arr = RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($sh_genres_array));

 $unique_genre = array_unique($genre_arr);
```